# Create a polygon around a polyline like a buffer

Tags: c#, geometry, polygon, polyline

I have looked around to find an example of how to take a polyline and create a buffer around it so I end up with a polygon.

So far I found out I need Minkowskis Sums to do so, but I can't get my head around to raw algorithm and translate that in to code.

I would prefer an example in C# or a walkthrough of the algorithm.

Comment: do you need convex polygon or just polygon?

Comment: I don't need a convex polygon.

Comment: Is it possible to use GDI+? If yes, then GraphicPath.Widen+(OutLine) + GetPathData

Comment: The 2D Geometry classes might also work, such as obtaining a PathGeometry with GetWidenedPathGeometry
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615692.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the OffsetPolygons() function in the [Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) library, but first you'd need to convert the polyline into a polygon. Do this by appending to the polyline a reverse copy of the polyline. But since duplicate vertices aren't allowed the reverse copy must exclude the first and last vertices: v1,v2,...,vn, v(n-1),...,v2.

[image]

Comment: It looks like Clipper only takes int values as the coordinates, but my coordinates is double values eg. (56.30174). Or am I missing some thing?

Comment: Regarding int values, see the FAQ in the documentation here: http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Overview/FAQ.htm

Comment: Do you know if the delta is divided by 2 or? because I'm polygon is as wide as my delta, and not double the width.

Comment: If the polyline is converted to a polygon as suggested above, then delta will be the amount the polygon expands on both sides of the original polyline. Therefore, the 'width' of your newly converted and expanded polyline will be twice delta.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample way to do something like this with the 2D objects already available with the .NET Framework, based off of this link

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/04/Rounded-Graphics-in-WPF.html

```
  // ...
  StreamGeometry geom = new StreamGeometry();

  DrawLines(geom);

  Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 10);
  p.LineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
  p.EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
  p.StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;


  PathGeometry pathGeomWide = geom.GetWidenedPathGeometry(p);
  PathGeometry pathGeom = pathGeomWide.GetOutlinedPathGeometry();

  Path myPath = new Path();
  myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
  myPath.Data = pathGeom;
  myCanvas.Children.Add(myPath);
  // ...

private static void DrawLines(StreamGeometry geom)
{
  using (var context = geom.Open())
  {
    context.BeginFigure(new Point(20, 20), false, true);
    context.LineTo(new Point(100, 20), true, true);
    context.LineTo(new Point(100, 100), true, true);
    context.LineTo(new Point(200, 100), true, true);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the 'Dot Spatial' library from Codeplex?

http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/

That uses Geos & Proj4 internally, which already contain all the functionality you need (Most of the worlds GIS servers & Products are built on these 2 code-bases!)

Failing that, you could use SQlite:

http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

and Spatialite:

http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/

Then using ADO.NET code in C# you can use simple GIS SQL Queries to perform your processing EG:

```
SELECT AsText(ST_Buffer(polyline,0.25),4326)
```

WHich will return a string something like:

```
MULTIPOLYGON((x y, x y, x y, x y......))
```

That you can then just parse.

No need to re-invent the wheel, when everything you need is readily available.

Comment: Only one problem, the Open Source license which 'Dot Spatial' is licensed under isn’t compatible with the software I’m working on.

Comment: What kind of licence do you need?